# How to get number of keys in std::map?

Tags: c++

Couldn't find on stackoverflow.

`std::map<T>.size()`

gives number of elements, not keys.

So how to get the number of keys?

Comment: How would the number be any different?

Comment: In a regular `std::map`, isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Map elements are key/value pairs, so the keys number, values number and elements number are all exactly the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
std::map<T>.size()
```

Gives the number of elements, *and* keys. It's a 1-to-1 match.

A `map` has a [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) of all keys you've tried to insert into the map. Insertion of an already existing key will be rejected if done via `insert`/`emplace` but the value-mapping will be replaced if the insertion is done using `operator[]`.

In a map a ***key*** can only *map* to *one* **value**. It's a dictionary.

---

**Variants:**

There are `multimap` (and `multiset`) versions. In a `multimap` multiple *equal* keys may map to different entities.

```
A -> foo 
A -> apa
B -> bar
B -> bepa
```

In this `multimap` the size would be `4` which is the number of mapped elements, not the number of unique keys (which isn't a concern for multimaps).

---

The `size()` member function of a regular `map` and a `multimap` return the number of mapped elements, which for a regular `map` is the same as the number of unique key values.

Answer (score 6):

The number of keys is equal to the number of elements in a map, for which its size would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since the keys are not repeated in a map, the size gives the number of keys in the map.

*Extra knowledge:-*
In the datatype multimap, the keys can be repeated, and over there the number of keys will not be equal to the size of the map as in the case of simple maps.